# Getting only the first word of a option inside value attribute in html

Tags: php, html

I am trying to select a previously selected value inside dropdown selection using php. My code is as follows

```
<?php

$selected_val = "Assistant Professor";
function generateSelect($type = 'text', $name = 'desgntn', $id = 'fac_dsgn', $options = array(), $default) {
    $html = '<select type="'.$type.'" name="'.$name.'" id="'.$id.'">';
    foreach ($options as $option ) {
       if ($option == $default) {
       $html .= '<option value='.$option.' selected="selected">'.$option.'</option>';
       } else {
            $html .= '<option value='.$option.'>'.$option.'</option>';
        }
    }

    $html .= '</select>';
    return $html;
}


$list = array("Lecturer", "Assistant Professor", "Associate Professor", "Professor", "Assistant Professor (On Leave)", "Associate Professor (On Leave)", "Professor (On Leave)");
$res = generateSelect('text', 'desgntn', 'fac_dsgn', $list, $selected_val);
echo $res;
?>
```

But the problem is I am always getting the **first word** of a multi spaced option inside **value** attributein **option tag** of html. for example: I am getting **Assistant** inside value tag for **Assistant Professor**. Is there any way so that I can always get the actual value with spaces?

Comment: You need to put the actual value into double quote characters. That is how html is defined.

Comment: OT: You can remove the `type` attribute, `<select>` doesn't have it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you forgot to enclose the option value in quotes:

it should be something like

```
$html .= '<option value="'.$option.'" selected="selected">'.$option.'</option>';
```

(note the double quotes around $option)

Hope it helps